# Can anyone explain how magento sync/index data to Elastic search in Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, reindex, indexing, elasticsearch, magento2.4.2

Can anyone explain how magento sync/index data to Elastic search in Magento 2.4.2. How it works and what are files called to index the products.

Answer (score 0):

**How it works**

- `php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext`

**What data indexed**

- Products by default

**what are files called to index the products**

- Modules start with Magento_ElasticSearch there are mainly around 2-3 modules which might interact with ElasticSearch.
  As your site runs on 2.4.2 then it would be ElasticSearch 7 so Magento_ElasticSearch7 and Magento_ElasticSearch modules will be the main modules from Magento framework point of view.
  Further, Magento_ElasticSearch module will call the client elasticsearch which is available in the magento-root/vendor directory.
  See this - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/composer.json#L38

Files which are available in the following directory are responsible for indexing.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/tree/master/src/Elasticsearch